# Can we share a document library with anonymous users

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, anonymous-authentication

we want to collect resumes from anonymous users. so can we configure a SharePoint online document library to be accessed by anonymous users to upload their resumes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

Best way to create one folder inside document library and share with option "**Anyone with the link**" option.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Important:** Make sure that below sharing option is set for site collection in SharePoint Admin Center

[image]

Anonymous user will something like this as below:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the useful reply...so users do not even need to login to be able to upload files inside the folder?

Comment: yes. correct.  just added screen shot in my answer which shows how it will look for anonymous users