# Why we can not share a folder inside a custom SharePoint online custom list with anonymous users

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharing, external-sharing

We have a SharePoint online site which allow Anyone Sharing. and we created a new custom list >> then inside the custom list we created a new folder. but when we tried to share the folder with "Anyone with the link" we got this message:-

[image]

so any advice?

Comment: I have already provided you solution for this in your original question [can-we-share-a-document-library-with-anonymous-users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303729/can-we-share-a-document-library-with-anonymous-users/303730#303730) i.e. you need to enable sharing for particular site to Anyone in SharePoint Admin Center. Just "Important" comment in your original post

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela this question, is abut creating folder inside a custom list and not a document library

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela this question, is about creating folder inside a custom list and not inside a document library –